# reversed expression in bsearch block not working

Tags: ruby, bsearch

```
ary = [1, 4, 6, 9]
(0...ary.size).bsearch { |i|
  ary[i] - 1
}                                   # => nil

1 - ary[i]                          # => 0
```

When the code is written in a form `ary[i] - 1` which doesn't work as expected.

What I am trying to do is to find the index of the number 1 in the array.

But `1 - ary[i]` can return the number's index correctly. Why doesn't `ary[i] - 1` work?

Comment: It's working as it is meant to work - please read - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch   Please clarify what is that you are trying to achieve

Comment: I've read the doc but the test `ary[i] - 1` should return 0, but it returns nil. I still don't understand it.

Comment: What is the goal of your code? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: updated with my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#bsearch` is meant to perform binary search to find an element that meets certain criteria. As per [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), if you return numeric values from the block, the `find-any mode` type of search is used.

The search starts at center of the sorted array - and if block returns negative value, it continues search in first half, and if block returns positive value, it continues the search in second half of the array.

In your case when you use `ary[i] - 1`, the value returned by block is always positive and search continues recursively on second half of the array - and never finds the value `1`.

Here is the code with some debug statements:

```
ary = [1, 4, 6, 9]
p (0...ary.size).bsearch { |i|
  puts "Elem: #{ary[i]} Index: #{i}"
  ary[i] - 1
}
```

Output:

```
Elem: 4 Index: 1
Elem: 6 Index: 2
Elem: 9 Index: 3
nil
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) returns an element of the array, not the index of a matching element.

You might want to use [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) instead.

Comment: Ruby 2.3 has `Array#bsearch_index`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the index of the element instead of the element itself, you need to use [`Array#bsearch_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview2/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index). Note: this method was introduced in Ruby 2.3, which at the time of this writing has not been released yet (it will be released on Christmas 2015).

The [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10730) for `Array#bsearch_index` contains a [comment](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10730#note-1) by Yusuke Endoh showing how to implement `Array#bsearch_index` (and in fact [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) as well) based on [`Range#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-bsearch):

```
class Array
  def bsearch_index(&blk)
    return enum_for(__method__) unless blk
    (0...size).bsearch {|i| yield self[i] }
  end
end
```

When either running Ruby 2.3 or using the above monkey patch, you can then do:

```
ary.bsearch_index(&1.method(:-))
```

in order to find the index of the `1` element in your array.

The reason why it doesn't work with

```
ary.bsearch_index {|el | el - 1 }
```

is simple: the block violates the contract of `bsearch_index` (and also `bsearch` since they are the same). The block needs to return a positive number for indices left of the one you are searching for, a negative number for indices right of the one you are searching for, and 0 for indices within the range you are searching for. Your block does the opposite.